# Detect if iPod library uses iTunes Match

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have been looking for a way using the MPMediaItem's or the MPMediaLibrary to detect if the device is connected to iTunes Match.  I can't find any API for this, does anyone know a way of detecting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to find out if the user is using iTunes Match though APIs.

You could always ask them - I doubt it'd be against TOS to have a popup, aside from the legal implications of using the terms "iTunes" or "iTunes Match" (Apple heavily discourages (ie rejects) apps which use any terms related to Apple or even Steve Jobs.)

If you posted more about what you were trying to do, we may be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: That is kind of the situation I am in, I prompted the user and was rejected because I used the words iTunes Match/

Comment: What functionality of your application requires that knowledge?

Comment: I cache of information about the iPod Library.  I'd like to be able to reload it if the library changes.  Unfortunately with iTunes Match it changes almost constantly.

Comment: Ah.  Do you get notified of changes?  It's possible that Apple's intended behavior is to not have applications keep caches of the library.

Comment: Currently the MPMediaLibrary gives no indication if it is set or if it changes.

Comment: Does the [Last Modified Date](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaLibrary_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMediaLibrary/lastModifiedDate) property tell you anything?

Comment: Nope, that is what changed almost constantly when using iTunes Match.